# Telegram bot - Get user response (command) from keyboard without slash

Tags: php, command, slash, telegram-bot

I want get a command from custom keyboard, without slash.
I read in other issue and inthe documentation, that this is not possible, the commands must always start with the ‘/’ symbol.
But in many bots i see that is possible.
For example @TriviaBot
I thought to get the string before the trigger start and add "/" to the string but without success.
Other solutions?

PS: I'm developing my bot in php using this API 
https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Telegram Bot Commands must be start with a slash `/`.

However, its are sent to bot as standard message, so the effective bot behavior is totally delegate to it.

If you want to use a string as command, you can do it simply processing the text message. I.e.:

```
if( $text == 'myCommand' )
{
    // Do Something...
}
```

Obviously, you have to consider possible ambiguities with a not-command message.

Comment: Thanks, at moment is a the most effective solution.
But don't think that @TriviaBot works in this way... and i would like to get to that solution. 
What do you think about it?

Comment: See [TriviaBot Commands](http://botsfortelegram.com/project/trivia-bot/). Other message are not commands. Are messages processed by bot. Yes, it works in this way. There is no alternative.

Comment: Great! I have a way to follow ;)